# Algorithms for finding the multiplicative order of an element in a group of integers mod m

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms

What are some algorithms for finding the multiplicative order of an element in a group of integers mod m, besides the naive one?

Comment: One can use a baby-step giant-step method, for example. Note that even computing $\phi(m)$ (the maximal possible order) itself is as hard as factoring $m$, as far as we know. So there's probably not a great algorithm for orders of elements. That being said, I'm sure it's a well-studied problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the prime factorization of $\lambda(m)\;$ or $\varphi(m)\;$ is known there are effective algorithms, see e.g. 
Algorithm 1.4.3 in H. Cohen's book *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory*. A better available source maybe **Algorithm 4.79: Determining the order of a group element** from *Applied Cryptography*  by A.J. Menezes et al. (you can download a pdf of ch. 4 from http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, it seems to be very similar to the one in the book mentioned by user61216 . whether you want to do it for $m$ directly or for the prime power factors of $m$ separately and then just take the lcm of the orders is up to you, I will assume we do it for $m$ directly. Let the element be $g$.

Let $\lambda(m) = p_1^{a_1} \dots p_k^{a_k}$.

We will now determine $v_{p_i}(o(g))$ for each $i$.

To do this firstly calculate $a=g^{\lambda(m)/p_i^{a_i}}$ using exponentiation by squaring, and then, while $a\not \equiv 1 \bmod m$ continue to raise $a$ to the $p_i'th$ power again with exponentiation by squaring. The value of $v_{p_i}( o(g) )$ is equal to the number of times you had to raise to the $p_i'th$ power.